# How to enable crypto.subtle for unsecure origins in Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, chromium, webcrypto-api

In Chrome 60, they added a *feature* that disables `crypto.subtle` for non-TLS connections. Our product needs to run a local server and forward some secure remote connections to `localhost` for security reasons. Because `localhost` isn't technically a named domain, we cannot use TLS--effectively making `crypto.subtle` unusable in Chrome (and chromium-based browsers like Opera), and forcing us to use a less secure shim like *asmCrypto.js*. Is there any way to tell Chrome to enable `crypto.subtle` through headers? Is there any way to disable the new *feature* in the settings that we can tell users about (worst case scenario)?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

> In Chrome 60, they added a feature that disables crypto.subtle for non-TLS connections

Not exactly, `crypto.subtle` is disabled for non-secure origins since first supported version (chrome 32?)

But `localhost` is considered a secure origin https://www.chromium.org/Home/chromium-security/prefer-secure-origins-for-powerful-new-features

> “Secure origins” are origins that match at least one of the following (scheme, host, port) patterns:
>
> - (https, *, *)
> - (wss, *, *)
> - (*, localhost, *)
> - (*, 127/8, *)
> - (*, ::1/128, *)
> - (file, *, —)
> - (chrome-extension, *, —)

So **you should be able to use Web Cryptographi Api on** `http://localhost`.

Are you using HTTPS for your site? It could be that you had a problem related to mixing HTTPS and HTTP. Chrome will block the HTTP connection to localhost. Then you could generate a self-signed certificate for 127.0.0.1 and launch your local server with HTTPS (similar to @SLaks answer but you will not need a `hosts` entry )

Comment: Actually we can't even use localhost for some other reason (don't remember why), but 127.0.0.1 fixes that issue and is identical (?) to localhost so that worked out.

Comment: So am I getting from this that it's supposedly idiotic then to want to roll my own encryption over HTTP in a country where HTTPS is blocked? The government tells me they want my stuff in plaintext and the browser committees agree?? Why in the hell would they block crypto over HTTP? Cryptography has zero technical dependency on HTTPS

Answer (score 2):

You should make a CNAME or `hosts` entry that points a valid domain at `127.0.0.1`, then get a (perhaps self-signed) certificate for that domain.